# Remove replicated files from xcode template project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, templates, project-template

I was trying to create some groups in my XCode Template but unable to map these groups to their respective folders.

To do that I have added my folders in  and give definition in  as given below

```
<key>Nodes</key>
<array>
  <string>Utilities</string>
</array>

<key>Definition</key>
<dict>
  <key>Utilities</key>
  <dict>
     <key>Path</key>
     <string>Utilities</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

It added the Groups in my project and map it to the physical folder. But a new problem I have faced is, it add the last files of a group as a folder reference and add all the files of group in this. Please refer the given image:

[image]

Here I have two files (`Constants.swift` & `Utils.swift`) and a folder `Extensions` inside the folder `Utilities`. How to remove the blue color folder (folder references)?

Answer (score 1):

While adding folder to your project, instead of selecting `create group` you have had selected `create folder reference`. That's causing it to appear blue.

Make sure you check the check box for `copy items if needed` is you want to add those files/folders to your project location.

Let me know, if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am creating a template in Xcode to define a structure. When I create my project using this template, these folders and files are already added in my project. Here I do not create any group or file.